# Android: Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE allows only single picking

Tags: android, android-intent, image-gallery

I want to open multiple images from the Android gallery using "Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE" intent filter:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Add images"), SELECT_MULTIPLE_IMAGES);
}
```

But whatever app I use (native gallery, QuickPic app), I can only select one single picture. The test device is running Android 5.1.

How can I pick multiple images?

Comment: `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` is a request, not a command, as with any `Intent` extras. There is no requirement that the activity you are starting honor them.

Comment: Do you know by chance an gallery app which supports multi-image picking using the ``EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`` parameter?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: Adding EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE works for me and allows me to select multiple images, however I have no idea how to get the Urls in onActivityResult.

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery.html

Comment: it requires Long press... no idea why it's the default behavior

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is currently working in one of my recent live application which covers selection of images using Gallary for 4.4 and above and below that using writing your own custom gallery.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_IMAGE_REQUEST_GALLERY);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(this, XYZ.class);
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
} else {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(this, XYZ.class);
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: What app are you (for instance) using to pick the images? I have tried QuickPic and the Samsung Gallery app but both seem only to support single picking. Your code looks very similar to mine.

Comment: I have tested above on Moto G and Nexus 4, Nexus 5 and Nexus 6 devices.

Comment: With the system gallery app?

Comment: YES using the System Gallery application recently published this app.https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.photofold&hl=en

Comment: it requires Long press to activate multiple select mode

Comment: Actually, you can use it since version 18 `Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2`

Comment: Doesn't appear to work on Pixel XL running Android 9 API 27... I get No apps can perform this action.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Extra used to indicate that an intent can allow the user to select and
 * return multiple items. This is a boolean extra; the default is false. If
 * true, an implementation is allowed to present the user with a UI where
 * they can pick multiple items that are all returned to the caller. When
 * this happens, they should be returned as the {@link #getClipData()} part
 * of the result Intent.
 *
 * @see #ACTION_GET_CONTENT
 * @see #ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data.getData() != null) {
            try {
                files.clear();
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String url = FileUtils2.getPath(this, uri);
                assert url != null;
                File file = new File(url);
                files.add(file);
                mPresenter.postAnnexData(files);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            //If uploaded with the new Android Photos gallery
            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
            files.clear();
            if (clipData != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                    Uri uri = item.getUri();
                    String url = FileUtils2.getPath(this, uri);
                    assert url != null;
                    File file = new File(url);
                    files.add(file);
                }
            }
            mPresenter.postAnnexData(files);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I pick 2 or 3 images I can read only the first one because `data.getData` is always not a null

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Add images"), SELECT_MULTIPLE_IMAGES);
```

Try

```
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_MULTIPLE_IMAGES); (Deprecated)
```

Or

```
someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

Avoid Using

```
Intent.createChooser
```

Answer (score 0):

Ther is no multi select in the native gallery, but you can do it with this  library :
https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick

Comment: Thanks for the link. There are plenty of other custom solutions out there as well. But I want to use the ``EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE``.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2019?