# Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE not working with Intent.ACTION_PICK when I test on Oppo (OS Version 7.1.1) in android

Tags: android

I am trying to add multi select image feature in my android app. This is how I am trying to do it

```
val gallery = Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI )
gallery.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
startActivityForResult(gallery, ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY)
```

In emulator with OS version 9, 10 it works perfectly fine. But when I test it on Oppo F5 with OS version 7.1.1 then it doesnt work.

But if I add `gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)`  then I can select multiple images on all devices but problem is that this method show images in very weird way and its not that much user friendly.

Any help will be highly apprecited, thanks

Comment: see here also although the answer below is correct for this question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70828005/3904109

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But when I test it on Oppo F5 with OS version 7.1.1 then it doesnt work.

`ACTION_PICK` is not documented to support `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`. Specifically:

- [The documentation for `ACTION_PICK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=en#ACTION_PICK) does not mention any supported extras
- [The documentation for `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=en#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE) only mentions `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`

Hence, you should not assume that any `ACTION_PICK` activity will do anything in response to your `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` extra.

> this method show images in very weird way and its not that much user friendly.

There are over 26,000 Android device models. There will be hundreds of different pre-installed apps for `ACTION_PICK` and `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` that might handle your request. How any of them render their UI, and how any of them react to unexpected extras, is up to their developers, not you or I. You seem to think that `ACTION_PICK` always results in one form of UI; that is incorrect.

> Any help will be highly apprecited, thanks

Either:

- Use `ACTION_PICK` and live with fact that `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` may be ignored, or
- Use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`/`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, or
- Use the `MediaStore` APIs directly and render your own image selector, or
- Use [one of the few dozen libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/157?sort=created) that implement an image selector